# Correct syntax to display a recurrent function in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit lost as to why this code is not displaying anything, it used to work when I didn't have a wrapper function for the button and I entered the parameter for the factorialize function manually in the script, what am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="factorializing">

  <h1> Factorialize a number </h1>

    <input type ="text" id ="number"/>
    <button id="factButton"> Factorialize</button>

  <h1 id="factorialized"> </h1>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("factButton").addEventListener("click", function(){

 function factorialize() {
   var input = document.getElementById("number").value;
   var output = document.getElementById("factorialized");

if (input === 0) {
   return output.innerHTML =  1;
}

else {
   return output.innerHTML = input * factorialize(input - 1) ;
}            
}
 });
```

Comment: why return statement?? output.innerHTML="valule"; should be enought!

Comment: It makes no difference, there's still no output. When I try this function in a console, it needs the return statement, otherwise it returns undefined.

Comment: You never call your `factorialize` function... 

Comment: As well as the function definition has not parameter, but in the else stament you add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:-

```js
document.getElementById("factButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var input = document.getElementById("number").value;
   var output = document.getElementById("factorialized");
  
  function factorialize(input) {
    if (input === 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return input * factorialize(input - 1);
    }
  }
  
  output.innerHTML = factorialize(input);
});
```

```html
<div class="factorializing">

  <h1> Factorialize a number </h1>

  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <button id="factButton">Factorialize</button>

  <h1 id="factorialized"> </h1>

</div>
```

this will recursively call your `factorialize` function and set the output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("factButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    document.getElementById("factorialized").innerHTML = factorialize(input);
});

function factorialize(n) {
    return (n <= 0) ? 1 : n * factorialize(n - 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="factorializing">

  <h1> Factorialize a number </h1>

  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <button id="factButton">Factorialize</button>

  <h1 id="factorialized"> </h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just write the value to the output each recursive call, while changing the value.

```js
document.getElementById("factButton").addEventListener("click", function() {


  var input = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("factorialized");
  
  output.innerHTML = ''
  
  factorialize(Number(input))

  function factorialize(input) {

    return output.innerHTML += '' + ((input === 0) 
      ? 1 
      : (input * factorialize(input - 1)))
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="factorializing">

  <h1> Factorialize a number </h1>

  <input type="text" id="number" />
  <button id="factButton">Factorialize</button>

  <h1 id="factorialized"> </h1>

</div>
```